# Error : not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm just trying to make a GUI application in PYTHON.  I'm a beginner and I'm stuck on this error.

Program:

```
from tkinter import *
import MySQLdb as mc

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Open Source : Python Project by Ashutosh Joshi")
root.config(bg="#150015")


First_Name=StringVar()
Last_Name=StringVar()
Roll_No = IntVar()
Phone_No=IntVar()
Email_ID=StringVar()


def database():
   fname=First_Name.get()
   lname=Last_Name.get()
   rollno=Roll_No.get()
   phonenumber=Phone_No.get()
   emailid=Email_ID.get()
   print(type(phonenumber))
   conn = mc.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="ashu12",database="python")
   cursor=conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO studentdetails (First_Name,Last_Name,Roll_No,Phone_No,Email_ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',(fname,lname,rollno,phonenumber,emailid))
   conn.commit()


label_0 = Label(root, text="STUDENT DATABASE",width=20,font=("bold", 25) ,fg="White",bg="#150015")
label_0.place(x=60,y=53)


label_1 = Label(root, text="First Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10),bg="Yellow",fg="Black")
label_1.place(x=80,y=130)

entry_1 = Entry(root,textvar=First_Name)
entry_1.place(x=250,y=130)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Last Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10),bg="Yellow",fg="Black")
label_2.place(x=80,y=180)

entry_2 = Entry(root,textvar=Last_Name)
entry_2.place(x=250,y=180)

label_3=Label(root,text="Roll No",width=20,font=("bold",10),bg="Yellow",fg="Black")
label_3.place(x=80,y=230)

entry_3 = Entry(root,textvar=Roll_No)
entry_3.place(x=250,y=230)

label_4=Label(root,text="Phone No",width=20,font= 
("bold",10),bg="Yellow",fg="Black")
label_4.place(x=80,y=280)

entry_4 = Entry(root,textvar=Phone_No)
entry_4.place(x=250,y=280)

label_4=Label(root,text="Email ID",width=20,font=("bold",10),bg="Yellow",fg="Black")
label_4.place(x=80,y=330)

entry_4 = Entry(root,textvar=Email_ID)
entry_4.place(x=250,y=330)

Button(root, text='Submit',width=20,bg='brown',fg='white',command=database).place(x=180,y=380)

root.mainloop()
```

**But I'm getting this ERROR**

```
<class 'int'>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\osproject.py", line 26, in database
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO studentdetails (First_Name,Last_Name,Roll_No,Phone_No,Email_ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',(fname,lname,rollno,phonenumber,emailid))
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 203, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "?" ("qmark") style for parameter substitution characters, but MySQLdb expects the "%s" ("format") style.

There are a number of different ways that Python database-driver modules may use to format variables for inclusion in SQL statements.  The style a particular module accepts can be determined by inspecting the module's `paramstyle` attribute:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.paramstyle
'format'
```

The full list of possible formats is [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

You need to replace each question mark in your INSERT statement's VALUE clause with "%s":

```
cursor.execute(
    """INSERT INTO studentdetails (First_Name,Last_Name,Roll_No,Phone_No,Email_ID) """
    """VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
    (fname,lname,rollno,phonenumber,emailid))
```

(I've broken the statement into two strings to make it more readable here on Stack Overflow - you don't need to do this in your own code).

Comment: idk but still there is an error which is unknown .....thanks for answering

Answer (score -2):

I,

firt of all, I advocate  an objects oriented programming style, anyway...

conn = mc.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="ashu12",database="python")

it's

conn = mc.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="ashu12",db="python")

Comment: I doubt this'll work without OP editing the source of his MySQLdb library, where `connect()` is defined. By doing this, he'll break the code for everyone else.